# getting a number out of 2 .txt files then compare them

Tags: batch-file

ok, I have 2 .txt files. `"server.txt"` and `"local.txt"`, `each have a number`, 
e.g

> 2 = server.txt

and

> 1 = local.txt.

I want so bat script reads both files and compares the numbers, another e.g

```
set local=1
set server=2
if %local% EQU %server% (
ECHO VERSION UP TO DATE
) else (
ECHO OUT OF DATE
)
pause
```

how would i set `local` to the number in the `local.txt` same for `server.txt`?

Comment: "each have a number" and where is the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the contents of the file local.txt as follows and that server.txt is similar.

```
1 = local.txt
```

Then, you can use something like the following to set `local` and `server`.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%n IN (server.txt) DO SET server=%%n
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%n IN (local.txt) DO SET local=%%n
```

Comment: hmm, what if its in a different location than the bat?

Comment: Use a different path inside the ( )

Comment: tried didn't seem to work so before each just "cd C:\" that seem to work tho